# Solve No matching DirectoryIndex without adding index

Tags: apache, logging, server

I want to solve or disable this error:

```
[Thu Jan 02 23:48:06.382888 2020] [autoindex:error] [pid 17460:tid 140351947863808] [client 92.36.xxx.xxx:49018] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /home/user/public_html/kodi/repository/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.html.var,index.htm,index.html,index.shtml,index.xhtml,index.wml,index.perl,index.pl,index.plx,index.ppl,index.cgi,index.jsp,index.js,index.jp,index.php4,index.php3,index.phtml,default.htm,default.html,home.htm,index.php5,Default.html,Default.htm,home.html) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

Folder **repository** doesn't have any index or .htacess file. 
**I need this folder without index file.**

I have apache 2.4 and this config:

```
<Directory "/home/user/public_html/kodi/">
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/home/user/public_html/kodi/repository/">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

**How to solve this error?**

Answer (score 1):

I solved this error.
I deleted code above, and enter this:

```
<Directory "/home/user/public_html/kodi">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Also deleted .htaccess in kodi folder. 
And made default.php empty file and now all works great!